# Is there a trick to invert a $3\times 3$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider any matrix which is $3\times3$ or bigger, but always square.

Is there a trick to invert quickly a matrix of this type without computing all the minors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: Adjoining the identity matrix and performing linear row reduction operations can be faster.

Comment: Cry and die....

Comment: You can use Gaussian elimination, or factorize the matrix through LU decomposition, the Cholesky decomposition, etc., and then invert the factors and multiply.

Comment: A fairly efficient method, at least more efficient than computing the matrix of cofactors, is to append the identity matrix $I$ at the end of your matrix $A$, like this $(A | I)$ and then do row reduction operations to this longer matrix until the $A$ part becomes $I$. Then in the place where $I$ was you will get $A^{-1}$.

Comment: On the other hand, for a human, the step of writing down the larger matrices $(A|I)$ for each step of the row reduction is time consuming. It can take longer than computing the cofactors and the determinant following the Rule of Sarrus. Sometimes what is better for a computer is not necessarily better for a person working with pen and paper and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is: *Gauß reduction*, downwards, then upwards, on your matrix. Simultaneously, perform the same row operations on the unit matrix. The transformed unit matrix is the inverse.

Answer (score 0):

It is often much more work to invert the matrix and use the inverse than to just go ahead and solve the linear system of equations of interest in the first place. Sure, matrix inverses are of huge *theoretical* importance, but you know the saying: "In theory, theory and practice are the same; in practice, they are very different".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method based on the Cayley-Hamilton theorem and Bocher's formula. Write the characteristic polynomial of an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ as $$\det(\lambda I-A)=\lambda^n+\beta_1\lambda^{n-1}+...+\beta_n.$$ The Cayley-Hamilton theorem says that$$A^n+\beta_1A^{n-1}+...+\beta_nI=0,\text {so} $$ $$A(A^{n-1}+\beta_1A^{n-2}+...+\beta_{n-1}I)=-\beta_nI$$ Thus, if $\beta_n=0$, the inverse does not exist; otherwise, the inverse is given by $$A^{-1}=\frac {-1}{\beta_n}(A^{n-1}+\beta_1A^{n-2}+...+\beta_{n-1}I)$$ To calculate the $\beta_{\nu}$ efficiently, use Bocher's formula $$\beta_1=-\mu_1,\text {    } \beta_{\nu}=\frac{-1}{\nu}(\beta_{\nu -1}\mu_1+...+\beta_1\mu_{\nu -1}+\mu_{\nu})$$ where $\mu_i=tr(A^i)$ The most effective way to use this formula is to evaluate the matrix polynomial by "synthetic division," so for $n=3$ we have $$A^{-1}=\frac {-1}{\beta_3}(A(A+\beta_1I)+\beta_2I)$$ Note that we do not have to store the powers of $A$. All we have to do is evaluate successive powers of $A$ and use them to calculate the traces and $\beta_i$as we go along. This method works over any field of characteristic 0 or of characteristic greater than $n.$ It also works over any commutative ring with identity in which all the elements 2,3, ... ,$n$ are invertible.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am really curious to understand better this. Do you have any link to a practicle example where this is used?